# TypeError : done is not a function?

Tags: node.js, express, passport-local

```
app.post('/sign', passport.authenticate('signup', {

    successRedirect: 'login',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true

}));

passport.use('signup', new LocalStrategy({

    usernameField: "Email",
    passwordField: "Password",
    passReqToCallback: true,

}, function(req, Email, Password, Name, Username, Confirm, done) {

    Name     = req.body.Name;
    Username = req.body.Username;
    Confirm  = req.body.Confirm;

    process.nextTick(function() {

        crud.findOne({ Email: Email }, function(err, user) {

            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }

            if (user) {
                return done(null, false, console.log("Email is already used"));
            }

            var data = new crud();

            data.Confirm  = Confirm;
            data.Password = Password;
            data.Email    = Email;
            data.Username = Username;
            data.Name     = Name;

            data.save(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                return done(null, data, console.log("Successfullt"));
            })
        })
    })
}));
```

Comment: Please add some description about the problem, not just plain codes.

Answer (score 2):

The callback you provided to `passport.use()` has too many parameters.

```
}, function(req, Email, Password, Name, Username, Confirm, done) {
```

The number and order of them is important, as the passport strategy will only provide certain arguments to assign their values. And, parameters aren't matched by their identifier/name in JavaScript.

With passport-local, and as you have `passReqToCallback` set to `true`, [there should be 4 parameters](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#parameters):

```
passport.use(..., function (req, username, password, done) {
    console.log(req      === arguments[0]); // true
    console.log(username === arguments[1]); // true
    console.log(password === arguments[2]); // true
    console.log(done     === arguments[3]); // true

    // ...
});
```

Any additional variables should be declared with `var` or `let` statements within the function's body:

```
var Name     = req.body.Name;
var Username = req.body.Username;
var Confirm  = req.body.Confirm;
```